# Why does my Apache display PHP code instead of executing it? (NOT A DUPLICATE)

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, server, config

My **Apache** server on my Ubuntu server (16.04 LTS) does **not** process my PHP code.
The file extensions are ending with **.PHP** and have `<?php` in them.

I have already tried **uninstalling** Apache and **resetting** the configs of Apache.

Unlike other posts, I am not using the file:\ protocol to execute the script(s).

this means that this is not a **Duplicate**.

I am using my servers external IP and I have set the apache config to allow all addresses and it is pointing to the right directory.

Here is a test script on my website to show the problem: http://bradsmc.tk/test.php

(This script should show your IP address, instead it shows it in the browser)

Comment: Do you have PHP installed? Your server isn't configured properly.

Comment: "Unlike other posts, I am not using the file:\ protocol to execute the script(s) this means that this is not a Duplicate" — The accepted answer on the duplicate question explores **6** possible reasons for the problem you describe. Using a file URI is only one of them.

Comment: I assume you've installed PHP and then fully rebooted your server? a lot of people somewhat strangely don't think about resetting and rebooting their systems when installing new stuff

Comment: Yes I have rebooted my server 3 times

Answer (score -1):

Check your mods_enabled folder, if there is php.so file

Comment: No, there isn't a PHP.so file in my mods-enabled folder. i am running the latest version of php and apache

Comment: it seems you either haven't PHP installed or enabled